# How activate Live Reload with Docker and Angular?

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose, package.json, livereload

I have a problem to run my angular application with live-reload.
Of course i have read some documentation but nothing works for me.

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services: 
  angular:
    container_name: angular
    build:
      context: ./angular
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - './angular:/app'
      - '/app/node_modules'
    ports:
    - 4201:4200
```

This is my Dockerfile

```
ARG NODE_VERSION=16.14.2

# Image Base
FROM node:${NODE_VERSION}-alpine

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

# Copy all local files in app folder in container
COPY . /app

# start app on default ip address
CMD ["ng","serve","--host","0.0.0.0","--poll"]
```

My environment is Windows 10 (--poll option)

I can see my application but the relod not works

command for build:

```
docker-compose up -d --build
```

command for launch

```
docker-compose up
```

thanks you for your help

Comment: A key reason to use Docker is that the container filesystem is generally isolated from anything happening on the host.  Do you mean to use Node directly on your host files, rather than introducing Docker in between your files and your language runtime?

Comment: No i can't, my company need to upgrade php, mysql, symfony, angular, node etc for a new project. it's why we want to use Docker :)